# What is the Replacement Method for CCArray in Cocos2dx 3.3?

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I Have One Game which develop in cocos2dx 2.2.3 and now i want to convert this game in cocos2dx 3.3

The Latest version but I cannot found about replacement of CCArray.

I read in some tutorial about vector but i don't know how can use it.Any Better Method or please tell me how can we use vector instead of CCArray.

my Cocos2d 2.2.3 Coding of CCArray is Below type

```
objectArray->CCArray::create();

objectArray->addObject(CCStringMake("1.png"));
objectArray->addObject(CCStringMake("2.png"));
objectArray->addObject(CCStringMake("3.png"));
objectArray->addObject(CCStringMake("4.png"));
objectArray->addObject(CCStringMake("5.png"));
objectArray->addObject(CCStringMake("6.png"));
objectArray->addObject(CCStringMake("7.png"));
objectArray->addObject(CCStringMake("8.png"));
objectArray->addObject(CCStringMake("9.png"));
objectArray->addObject(CCStringMake("10.png"));

objectArray->retain();
```

How to convert above Code in Vector Or any instead mehod for cocos2dx3.3 ? Please Tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in .h file declare the array using vector

```
cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Sprite *>objectArray;
```

in .m file use below code to addobject

```
objectArray.pushBack(sprite);
```

and for use either use for or at for the perticuler access object
`objectArray.at(2);`

```
for(auto str: objectArray)
{
   Sprite *sprite21 = dynamic_cast<Sprite *>(str);
}
```

Comment: Hey @anil72178 - your edit request removed the final `for` snippet. If this is not needed, or if you have done something differently, please leave a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector<String> frames;
frames.pushBack("data1");
frames.pushBack("data2");

for(auto sp : frames)
{

}
```

Comment: Code only answers - whilst technically correct - are usually much improved by including some explanation as to what's going on.